# Resize image and keep original on upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, resize, blueimp

I'm using [blueimp's jQuery file uploader](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) and I'm wondering how I could resize an image to a specific width upon upload, put it into a specific directory, all while keeping the original image.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function(e, data) {
        var uploadErrors = [];
        var acceptFileTypes = /^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;

        if (data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
            uploadErrors.push('Invalid file type.');
        } else if (data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 1000000) {
            uploadErrors.push('Image over size.');
        }

        if (uploadErrors.length > 0) {
            $('.errors').html(uploadErrors);
        } else {
            data.submit();
        }                    
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
    }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you resize it on the server side

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury How would I achieve what I need doing it server side?

Comment: depends on your server side scripting language.

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury PHP.

Comment: Are you basically using the demo right now - and your files are being uploaded to `php/files`?

Comment: @TanvirChowdhury That's correct.

Comment: take a look at Uploadcare service, it's not strictly an answer to the question, but you can achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the resize with [PHP-GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

There are several references if you google it. Here is [one](http://salman-w.blogspot.com.br/2008/10/resize-images-using-phpgd-library.html).